# maximum distance in between points in taxicab metrics

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let's define distance between two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ as
$$|x_2-x_1| + |y_2-y_1|$$.

There are given some points.
I think how to find maximum distance between two arbitrary points (among given points).  My inituition is following:
Let's find point $(x, y)$ such that $x+y$ is maximal and $(a, b)$ such that $a+b$ is minimal.   I don't know idea about corectness. It is only intuition. Could you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea as stated is incorrect.  For example consider the points
$$
\{(-100,100),(100,-100),(1,1),(-1,1)\}
$$

Comment: You are right, so can you help me solve this problem ? I think also about third dimension.

Comment: I think that the only solution that will always work is to try every pair of points.

Comment: Ok, maybe I say more. I would like to find algorithm for this problem.

Comment: Post a new question.  Perhaps you should post the question to a programming site like stackoverflow.